# react native in terminal suddenly not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I was using it fine but it suddenly became unresponsive. I've tried
react-native start, init, and run-ios

its just stuck
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with permission. I have to run as root for it to work. Fixed it by reinstalling it with brew